# An error occurred while processing amazon purchase

Tags: android, amazon-in-app-purchase

We are working on an App for firestick TV and found the issue with amazon in app purchase. The problem is given below:

[image]

> An error occurred while processing your purchase
>
> And error occurred while attempting to purchase this item. Please try again.

PurchaseResponse:

```json
{
"requestId": {
"encodedId": "4acc4453-5720-4XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx"
},
"requestStatus": "FAILED",
"userData": {
"marketplace": "IN",
"userId": "hknPpXJBn4qzKPIXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
}
}
```

@market place->India

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. did you get ant solution for it. Please help , i am stuck at this point since last 4 days. Any help would be appreciable.